# Problema em um botão que possui hover no css

Tags: html, css

Uma parte do texto do botão tem que estar destaque e ja tentei colocar a tag , a tag  e criar uma class no css com a font weight: bold, mas sempre ao passar o mouse no botão o mesmo a parte do texto em destaque fica com uma sobra escura, e não consegui achar uma solução, coloquei uma imagem para mostrar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="botao"><span>Try it free 7 days</span> then $20/mo. thereafter</button><br>
<div class="formulario">
  <form>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Last name" placeholder="Last Name "><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="e-mail" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input class="form-control submit btn-color" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Claim your free trial"><br>
  </form>
  <footer>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <a href="">Terms and Services</a></footer>
</div>
```

e continuou aparecendo como esta na imagem que coloquei.

Comment: use um seletor composto, `<span>  filho direto de <button>`  dessa forma `button.botao span { text-shadow: none;}`

Comment: Não conseguimos reproduzir o problema. Deve ter algo mais que não nos foi informado como sobreposição de estilos ou o uso de framework css. Já tentou usar `background: none;` ?

Comment: Sim, tentei o background: none; e continuou, estou usando o framework bootstrap.

Comment: @stack.cardoso deu certo, só acrescentei o hover para colocar o mesmo 'background button.botao span:hover{
    background: hsl(248, 54%, 63%);
    text-shadow: none;
}'

Answer (score -3):

Talvez já exista outro CSS estilizando a tag . Se você quiser sobrescrever um estilo já existente você deve inserir o !important após o atributo da classe pra dizer que ele é mais importante. Desta forma:

background-color: none **!important**

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).